# How can I change the handwriting input language in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, language, tablet, handwriting

I'm in a school where all students have tablet PCs, where they use the handwriting (text recognition) function quite a bit. Recently one of the language teachers has asked if they can enter French accents using this method - it seems that one definitely can using windows 7 ultimate, but we're using Pro. I understand that if one changes the entire input language, then this should work, but it doesn't seem to. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appears that what I want requires win7 ultimate or enterprise :(

Answer (score 0):

Hmm I'm not at my Windows 7 PC at the moment but can't you just change the language in Control Panel -> Regional & Language -> Keyboards & Languages -> Change Keyboards, and add French in? You'll need to change it to French after adding it.

Comment: This changes the keyboard input language, but doesn't let me input French handwriting via the pen.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft only allows language packs to be added to the Enterprise and Ultimate Editions of Windows 7.

The following guide shows how to add language packs to a Windows 7 DVD so you can install Windows 7 Starter, Home Basic, Home Premium, Professional and Ultimate in your language of choice.

[TUTO: slipstream MUI language pack in installation DVD](http://forums.mydigitallife.info/threads/5189-TUTO-slipstream-MUI-language-pack-in-installation-DVD?p=80057#post80057)

This will require the re-installation of Windows 7, and assumes you have the installation DVD or iso.

Bonne chance.